# Why can I not use a number less than 0 in an argument to paramaterise a double java?

Tags: java, double

Why does this work:

```
public static double[][] param(double[][] data){
    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<data[0].length;j++){
            if(j!=1){
           data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1/10;//for some reason didn't accept as argument           

            }
            System.out.println(data[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return data;
}
```

with the following output:

> 13581.0
>   337.42900390625
>   13571.0
>   337.1949951171875
>   13561.0
>   336.59599609375
>   13541.0
>   336.356005859375
>   13531.0
>   336.072998046875
>   13521.0
>   335.7989990234375
>   13511.0
>   335.5219970703125
>   13501.0

but this doesn't :

```
public static double[][] param(double[][] data, double param){

    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      for (int j=0;j<data[0].length;j++){
            if(j!=1){
           data[i][j] = data[i][j] * param;            

            }
            System.out.println(data[i][j]);
      }
    }
    return data;
}
```

With the following (incorrect) output.

> 13581.0
>   0.0
>   13571.0
>   0.0
>   13561.0
>   0.0
>   13541.0
>   0.0
>   13531.0
>   0.0
>   13521.0
>   0.0
>   13511.0
>   0.0
>   13501.0

Both methods compile fine but when I try to run the second one it makes all the data in the first column = 0.

They are both being called in the same way the only difference is that one gets the 1/10 value from the argument and the other it is hard coded onto (not ideal but it's the only way I can get it to work for some inexplicable reason).

Is this problem happening due to the fact it does not like being paramaterised by a number < 0?

Comment: what are outputs? how do you call methods?

Comment: You have to show how the value of `param` is calculated in the second example. I'll bet it's `double param = 1/10;`, in which case integer division is being done and results in zero. It works in the first example because the expression is evaluated left-to-right and conversions to double happen in the right order.

Comment: There has *got* to be like a hundred duplicates of this question.

Comment: @cHao the problem with questions like these is that you cannot search them until you know the answer because you have no idea what the cause of the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by calling the the method

```
public static double[][] param(double[][] data, double param)
```

as

```
param(data, 1/10);
```

the value 1/10 is evaluated to `0`  because of the integer division so the above method call is same as

```
param(data, 0);
```

the statement

```
data[i][j] = data[i][j] * param;
```

in param() is equivalent of

```
data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 0 /*`param`*/;
```

that is why it makes all the data in the first column = 0 in the second case.

Where as in the first case it does not make data in the first column = 0 because the statement:

```
data[i][j] = data[i][j] * 1/10;
```

is converted into it equivalent as follows

```
data[i][j] = (data[i][j] * 1)/10;// the (data[i][j] * 1) will return a double value
```

when a `double/int` operation is done result will be a `double`. 
That is why the first case works as you expected where as second case does not.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So, the reason it didn't evaluate the fraction to zero in the first example was because it was doing all the procedure at once? If not, what was it that was happening to make that work for me?

Comment: Edit to my answer includes the reason why the first case was working for you! check out.

Comment: There seems like a lot of things to watch out for with java! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

It would work fine if `param` is initialized as

`double param = 0.1;`
or

`double param = 1.0d/10.0d;`

instead of

`double param = 1/10;`

because in `double param = 1/10` case when `1/10` is executed, there are two integers being used in operation which are rounded off to zero and assigned to param.

it worked fine in first method posted by you because the expression was being calculated form left to right since both `*` and `/` have same arithmetic operator priority.